# Dismiss UIView border drawn as CGRect around CALayer.frame

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, cgrect

I'm adding borders to views like this:

```
extension UIView {
  func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width, height:width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
  }
}
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
textLbl.addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor.white, width: 1)
```

in viewWillAppear:

```
textLbl.text = "placeholder text \(variableLengthText)"
```

How can I dismiss the border I've drawn using the above extension?

Answer (score 0):

> In other views (for instance a ToolBar) as a sloppy hack, I would just write over the border with one matching the background color of the object so it didn’t overlap (for instance on a screen orientation change)

Well, that was always wrong, so the first thing to do is to stop doing it.

This has nothing to do with `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillAppear`. The signal that the view is changing size is that its `layoutSubviews` is called. So you could implement `layoutSubviews` to remove the border layer and add a new one at the new size.

But it would be even better to add a subview to the label, consisting of a clear background except for the border. That way, the subview could be configured using constraints to grow and shrink together with the label *automatically* with no need for any code. Here's a screencast demonstrating that implementation; the red line is the right border:

[image]

Comment: I'm aware that was always wrong, and my main questions is how do I access the object. I'm not asking for best practices, but feel free to continue sharing ;)

Comment: I don't see that "main question" anywhere in your question, and I don't know what "access the object" even means.

Comment: "Dismiss UIView border drawn as CGRect around CALayer.frame"

Comment: I'm asking how to remove the rect, but I guess I should be asking how to remove the layer

Comment: Using my example above, how do I access the border layer?

Comment: Added a screencast showing my suggested approach in action.

Comment: "how do I access the border layer" You didn't keep a reference to it, so that's not easy. If you were going to need to access it, you should have kept a reference. You could try saying `self.layer.layers[0]` but I don't guarantee that, because some built-in view types already have sublayers so I don't know which one is yours. An advantage of the second approach is that there is nothing to remove and replace and thus there is no need to keep any reference to anything; the border just moves together with the resizing of the label.

Comment: I couldn't get your storyboard implementation to work, but I did get it to work in code using your comment that I didn't keep a reference to it. Please update your answer to explain the IB solution, or adding a reference in code with an example and I'll accept it. I've updated my question so it's more clear and concise. Otherwise I'll post my answer which I'm sure is sloppier than yours will be

Comment: You do what you have to do. I've given my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While @matt's storyboard solution looks elegant, I'm unable to implement it. I did however get it to work by setting the layer.name field in the extension and checking for it in ViewWillLayoutSubviews

```
extension UIView {
  func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width, height:width)
    border.name = "topBorder"
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
  }
```

In `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` I call:

```
    if self.textLbl.layer.sublayers != nil {
  for layer in textLbl.layer.sublayers! {
    if layer.name == "rightBorder" || layer.name == "leftBorder" || layer.name == "topBorder" {
      layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
  }
}
```

In `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` I call:

```
textLbl.addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor.white, width: 1.5)
```